# Selenium cannot load a page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am using selenium to automatically login website https://fiverraffiliates.com/loginaffiliate/. But Selenium did not load the page.

It just displayed a white website and nothing happened (below image).

This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

url = "https://fiverraffiliates.com/loginaffiliate/"

while True:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        username_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "user")
        print("Success")
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.refresh()
```

[blank website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD6p5.png)

Please guide me solution for this problem. I need use selenium to access this website and automatically login.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it as well and it did not work for me. My assumption is that they are detecting Selenium usage and not loading the site intentionally.